# SailsJS and PassportJS Facebook auth

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I'm trying to use Passport with SailsJS.
The `passport.authenticate('facebook')` method is never called and no response is sent.
I initialize Passport and my strategies in `config/passports.js`.

**`config/passport.js`**:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findOne({id: id}, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  /* IDS */
}, (token, refreshToken, profile, next) => {
    /* logic here */
  })
}));
```

I initialize passport and serialization methods.

I setted `passport.init()` and `passport.session()` middlewares in the `config/http.js` file following this order :

```
'startRequestTimer',
'cookieParser',
'session',
'passportInit',
'passportSession',
```

The route `/auth/facebook` uses the following controller :

```
passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email', 'user_about_me']},
      (err, user) => {
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          if (err) return res.send(err);
          return res.redirect('/');
        })
      });
```

All my requests time out when I call `/auth/facebook`, passport never calls my authentication method.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

passport.authenticate returns a function, which you have to call in order to work.

Here's how I use it:

```
'facebook': function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email', 'user_about_me']}, function (err, user) {
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if(err) {
        res.redirect('user/login');
      } else {
        res.session.user = user;
        res.redirect('/');
      }
    });
  })(req, res, next);
},
```